# When is $\frac{(2x+5)}{(3x+4)}$ not in lowest terms?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

What are the integer value(S) for x where $$\frac{2x+5}{3x+4}$$ is **not** in lowest terms?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The will occur exactly at those integers $x$ for which $\gcd(2x+5, 3x+4) \neq 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$gcd(2x+5,3x+4)=gcd(2x+5,x-1)=gcd(7x,x-1)$,
but $gcd(7x,x-1)=7$ if $x=7k+1$ and $gcd(7x,x-1)=1$ in any other case.

Thus the fraction is not in lowest terms only when $x=7k+1$,for any integer k.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain how gcd(2x+5,3x+4)=gcd(2x+5,x−1)? I'm new to this topic...

Comment: It is a property of gcd.In more detail it holds that:
$gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,b-ka)$, where k is an integer.
In our example we have that:
$gcd(2x+5,3x+4)=gcd(2x+5,3x+4-2x-5)$